# problem to input and display array of strings

Tags: arrays, c

I was trying to display array of strings given by user. I used char to declare string and for loop for input and display. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{ 
  int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    strings st[n];
    
    for( i = 0; i<n ; i++){
        scanf("%s",st[i]);
    }
    for( i = 0; i<n ; i++){
        printf("%s \n",st[i]);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this C or C++? In the future, please only tag a single language.

Comment: given the VLA, it's C.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Or compiler extensions.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Fair enough

Comment: What is `strings`? There's no such type in C. Perhaps you should take some more time with your book or tutorial to learn what a "string" is in C.

Comment: use (char*)[] or char[][] to represent string list in C

Comment: "wrong with the code." --> Code calls `scanf("%s",st[i]);`, yet the value of `st[i]` is indeterminate.  `st[i]` needs a value (e.g. pointer to allocated memory) first before passing to  `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
for( i = 0; i<n ; i++)
{
    scanf("%s",st[i]);
```

before this call to `scanf()`  need to allocate memory for the `st[i]` pointer to be pointing at.  perhaps via

```
st[i] = malloc( 1024 );  
if( ! st[i] ) 
{ 
    perror( "malloc failed" ); 
}  

else 
{ 
    if( scanf("%1023s",st[i]) != 1 ) 
    { 
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed\n" ); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, you have to do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
  int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char st[n][100]; // Line 7
    
    for( i = 0; i<n ; i++){
        scanf("%s",st[i]);
    }
    for( i = 0; i<n ; i++){
        printf("%s \n",st[i]);
        
    }
}
```

This program can read strings up to 100 characters long. To change this limit, modify the value in the second bracket in line 7.

Second, there is no such type as strings in C. If you've seen this type on the internet, you've most likely been looking at C++ code. C++ and C are different programming languages - they're not the same. If you'd like to do it in C++ leave a comment and I'll show you how to do it.

Comment: "This program can read strings up to 100 characters long" is true if the length includes the _null character_, else it should be  "up to 99".  Better to use `"%99s"` than `"%s"` here.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution  for your problem but try to see more tutorials about c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
   char st[n][50];

    for( i = 0; i<n ; i++){
        scanf("%50s",st[i]);
    }
    for( i = 0; i<n ; i++){
        printf("%s \n",st[i]);

    }

}
```

Comment: #include <string.h> is not needed. It also doesn't work in plain C code. (string.h is only for C++)

Comment: `scanf("%s",st[i]);`, without a width limit, is bad like [gets()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Comment: Also, check the return value from `scanf("%d",&n);` and the other `scanf`

Comment: width limit fixed . #include <string.h> was a fault from previous program but #include <string.h> is work for c check this link [link](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-function/string-h-library-functions/)

Answer (score 0):

A more dynamic approach using array of `char *`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x)

#define LINESIZE 255
#define SCAN_LINE " %" STR(LINESIZE) "[^\n]"

int main() {
    int n,i ;
    char *buf;
    char (*lines)[LINESIZE];
    printf("Enter number of lines: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    buf  = malloc(n*sizeof(lines));

    lines = (char (*)[])buf;

    for( i = 0; i<n ; i++){
        scanf(SCAN_LINE,lines[i]);
    }
    for( i = 0; i<n ; i++){
        printf("%s \n",lines[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Off by 1.  String size needs to be at least one more than  the width used in the `scanf()` format.